# Receiving 502 when trying to connect daphne websocket nginx

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, django-channels, daphne

I'm getting an

`Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502`

when trying to connect to wss://my.domain.com/ws/

daphne entrypoint:

```
daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=certKey.pem myapp.asgi:application
```

my nginx conf:

```
upstream channels-backend {
  server 0.0.0.0:8001;
} 
server {
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server_name servername;
  server_tokens off;
  ssl_certificate certKey.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key key.pem;
  ...
  location /ws/ {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ $1 break;
    proxy_pass http://channels-backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  }
}
```

And in my front end:

```
let wsStart = 'ws://';
  if (loc.protocol === 'https:') {
    wsStart = 'wss://';
  }
const endpoint = '${wsStart}my.domain.com/ws/';
const socket = new WebSocket(endpoint);
```

If in my daphne entrypoint I add only -b 0.0.0.0:8001 works fine and connect over ws:// but I need to connect over wss://

Any ideas?